# I need help to correctly implement the Comparable interface

Tags: java, comparable, compareto

I have a builded a class called Melody that reads the following lines from a file and stores them into an array called notes of type Note. The columns are: Time in 1/100 second ticks, Note Number, Velocity, Length.

```
0 60 100 24
25 72 100 24
100 60 100 24
50 60 100 24
75 72 100 24
```

For my course work I need to implement the Comparable interface. I need to make my Note class Comparable, so that notes are ordered based on time,and if two notes occur at the same time, then I need to put the note with the lower note number first. I need some help as I have got stuck trying to correctly implement the comparaTo method and to print out the result. I would appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

This is my Note class

```
public class Note implements Comparable <Note> {  

    private int time;
    private int noteNumber;
    private int velocity;
    private int length;

    public Note (int time,int noteNumber,int velocity,int lenght){

        this.time = time;
        this.noteNumber = noteNumber;
        this.velocity = velocity;
        this.length = lenght;  
    }

    public String toString()
    {

        String s =  time +" "+ noteNumber + " " + velocity + " " + length;

        return s;   
    } 

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Note o) {

        return Integer.compare(time, o.time);
    }
}
```

This is my Melody class

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Melody  {

    Note [] notes = new Note[5];

    public Melody() throws IOException{

        FileReader fr = new FileReader ("/Users/enricomomo/Desktop/Text/file2.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (fr); //Info stored into a buffer

        String line = br.readLine(); //Lines are read from the buffer and stored into a variable

        int lineCounter = 0;

        while  ( line != null )//When reached the end of the file the while loop stops 

        { 

            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line, " ");

            int time = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
            int noteNumber = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
            int velocity = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
            int length = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());

            System.out.println(line + " " + lineCounter);

            Note n = new Note(time,noteNumber,velocity,length);

            notes[lineCounter] = n;

            line = br.readLine();

            lineCounter ++;
        }

        br.close(); 
    }

    public void contet(){

        for ( int i = 0; i < notes.length; i ++)
        {

            System.out.println(notes[i]);                    
        }
    }

    public String toString()
    {
         String rtn = "";

         //Code to create a String version of the object 

         for ( int i = 0; i < notes.length; i ++)
            {

                rtn += "\n"; 
            }

         return rtn; 
    }
}
```

And this is my Test class

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Melody m = new Melody();

        System.out.print(m);

        m.contet();
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `time` and `noteNumber` are `int`:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Note o) {
    if (time == o.time)
        return Integer.compare(noteNumber, o.noteNumber);
    else
        return Integer.compare(time, o.time);
}
```

`compareTo` needs to return a negative, a zero or a positive number,
depending whether the 1st item is less, equal or greater than the 2nd. 
After you fill the array of `Note` objects call:

```
Arrays.sort(notes);
```

Comment: Where exactly should I implement the compareTo method in the Melody class?

Comment: No need to implement in Melody class. It should be implemented in Note class.

Comment: It does not seem to change the result. What should I do in the Melody class to make it work, I mean to print out the new result

Comment: Which result. Did you compare any objects of type Note?

Comment: As a general pattern, I think it's easier to use `if (time != o.time) return time - o.time;` - it cascades better as you add more fields for comparison.

Comment: shall I just do n.compareTo(n) before storing the n in the array of notes?

Comment: No store the items in any order and then call: `Arrays.sort(notes);`

Comment: `Arrays.sort()` will use the `compareTo()` method to do the sorting.

Comment: Where exactly should i put Array.sort ()?

Comment: After you fill the array of Notes.

Comment: After br.close() maybe?

Comment: @AndyTurner I don't disagree, but this is a 2 field case so each way can be as simple.

Comment: As a guideline for comparing ints, it's better to use `if (time != o.time) return Integer.compare(time, o.time);`. Using explicit subtraction can risk getting incorrect results when using very large ints that may result in overflow.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException this is more than right. I will include it in my answer.

Comment: 2 60 100 24 0
25 72 100 24 1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
100 60 100 24 2
50 60 100 24 3
75 72 100 24 4

Comment: Which line gives the error? Did you debug or did the error log contain the line number?

Comment: The occur occurs when it starts comparing, after the second line

Comment: You mean `return Integer.compare(noteNumber, o.noteNumber);`?

Comment: @Momissimo I think the NullPointerException is due to the fact that `notes.length` is always 10, but you may not have all 10 notes filled in the array. You need to think about how to determine the _actual_ length of the array rather than the declared length.

Comment: @Momissimo if your array's length is 10 and you insert less than 10 objects then the empty positions are filled with null objects. If you try to add more than 10 objects, you will get an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception.

Comment: If the array has null objects then when you try to sort it you will get for sure NullPointerException.

Comment: I have changed the size of the array to 5, Thanks it works perfectly :)

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
public class Note implements Comparable <Note>
{
  ...

  @Override
  public int compareTo(Note o)
  {
    int result;
    result = time - o.time;
    if (result == 0)
      result = noteNumber - o.noteNumber;
    if (result == 0)
      result = velocity - o.velocity;
    return (result);
  }  
}
```

After that, you need to sort your array:

```
public Melody() throws IOException
{
  ...

  Arrays.sort(notes);

}
```